# Fetching Data from PL-SQL Table as OUT parameter in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am executing a procedure from java code, which has 2 out parameters, One of those is a Object table. here is the overview of package

```
PROCEDURE SalesProc (
  p_S_table             IN t_s_table
, p_T_table             IN OUT t_t_table           
, x_message             OUT VARCHAR2
```

)

t_table is IN OUT parameter which contains several String and Numbers into it. Before executing the package I am creatng an SalesObject array and setting into it.

Here, the aim is to get some value from t_table using resultSet.

**the source I am trying to get working is:**

```
 callstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY,"T_TABLE");
 callstmt.setArray(2, mySalesObjectArray);
 callstmt.execute();
 java.sql.Array aa = callstmt.getArray(2);
 ResultSet rs = aa.getResultSet();

 while(rs.next()){
     String ss = rs.getString(1);
 }
```

---

Following line is giving  "`java.sql.exception`"

```
  String ss = rs.getString(1);
```

I am also trying to cast it into Object type as follows

```
 salesObject[] sArray = (salesObject[])callstmt.getArray(2);
```

Which is throwing classCastException.
"`classcastException.Cannot cast java.lang.Object[2][id=16062] to java.lang.String[]`"

---

**how can I avoid these exceptions?**

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What is the definition of T_TABLE?  etc etc.   You need to give us a little more to work with.

Comment: "it is not working" Please give us specifics.  Inb what way is it not working?  Describe the observed behaviour, including error messages,etc.  If you don't provide details you won't get an answer.

Comment: Could you post the structure (preferably syntax) of the underlying procedure please?

Comment: Try casting to `Object[]`: `Object[] sArray = callstmt.getArray(2)`

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 parameters, the counting starts from 1 from the left most parameter:

1. p_S_table
2. p_T_table
3. t_t_table

I use Oracle as a DBMS but haven't use IN/OUT parameters but I'm sure that if u change youre procedure into a function (because a function returns something) that takes the IN parameters and returns the OUT one, same code will work.

As for the casting here:

```
salesObject[] sArray = (salesObject[])callstmt.getArray(2);
```

your `salesObject` class should implement either `ORAData` or `SQLData`.
`SQLData` seems nicer.